# Convert Array to Date yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: typescript

with typescript I'm doing the next:

```
 var today = new Date();
   var startDate = today;
   startDate.setDate(today.getDate() - 7);
   var StartDate = startDate.toISOString().split('T')[0];
   var endDate = new Date();
   endDate.setDate(today.getDate() + 7);
   var EndDate = endDate.toISOString().split('T')[0];
```

I'm doing this by this way because I need a format with yyyy-mm-dd but also I need it in "Date" type, but it is returning me an array but I don't know how to change it into an Date.

In this case EndDate and StartDate are the finish vars that I'm gonna use.

Comment: `yyyy-mm-dd` is a string, though?

Comment: yes, but it should be a Date type @ksav

Comment: also I need to use that date format because I have with that format on DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it like this [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=16#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAKzjMAKKAuRARAQygFMAaRA3AsAT3IGdd6oAndAcwEpEBvAKESDQkWAkTA4LALZEMUqrW79BKxABtiUcYgC8iMMQDuiAJJgoagHSESAFRhTiAMUkyoGAOTEwH8lM4A3AKqiCyaICxIwJYS0rJQgcGIAL5JYVARSASWMgAOGLFunJao6Bj0ial8GloEuogA2jw0xAQsuB5gII5sEB7J5DxSCFAAFh30o5JQ-YMAJgQ0HV09MH3JALpBNYj09aWYBsY2ZBTkHgC0HokQCPRwGpZqcOzlgUA)

```
function join(t: Date, a: any, s: string) {
   function format(m: any) {
      let f = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', m);
      return f.format(t);
   }
   return a.map(format).join(s);
}

let a = [{year: 'numeric'}, {month: 'short'}, {day: 'numeric'}];
let s = join(new Date, a, '-');
console.log(s);
```